# Exterior algebra on a given number of generators?

Tags: reference-request, supergeometry

I just started studying supermanifolds and I need to understand how to construct the exterior algebra on $q$ generators. Can anyone recommend me a a book which deals with it?

I know this is an algebraic concept which can be dealt out of supergeometry so I'm looking for an abstract treatment.

Thanks.